# Streamlit does not open the web browser

Tags: python, streamlit

I am trying to run an app using Streamlit. The browser (localhost) does not open for me. Instead I get this warning message:

```
 Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
  command:

    streamlit run /Users.......summarizer.py
```

I understand that streamlit requires separate compilation and hence we need to use `streamlit run app.py` to run the app.
When I run the above (`streamlit run app.py`), I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'click' has no attribute 'get_os_args'
```

I have the following click version installed, `click==8.0.4`

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Could you post all your dependent modules?

Comment: It seems that you are not running `streamlit run app.py` or `pip install click` in the good environment. What is the output of `which streamlit`?

Comment: Upgrading to the most recent version of Streamlit should resolve this issue